# ASP.NET View Component Fails to Load in Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

My web application runs perfectly fine in Windows. I even have it running in production on a Linux server for years without issue.

Now that I try to open the solution on a Linux desktop with JetBrains Rider IDE, the project fails to load at all. I boot up the Windows VM and the very same project runs.

First of all, what is to blame, JetBrains Rider, ASP.NET, or my installation? I've been developing desktop apps without any issue.

I created a new web application to see whether ASP.NET runs and it does. I started copying everything over file by file.

I got `Pages/Shared/Components` that contains `ProductBox.cs` and `ProductBoxModel.cs` and it runs fine. I add the file `Pages/Shared/Components/ProductBox/Default.cshtml` and it fails to load. There is no error or anything.

Running it simply opens a blank page in Firefox. In Chrome, it will give a 404 error after a security warning. I delete that one specific file and the application starts again.

I found this issue: [View Component Loading Issue on Production ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251649/view-component-loading-issue-on-production-asp-net-core)

Moved `Pages/Shared/Components/` to `Views/Shared/Components`. The problem persists.

The View Component breaks the application in Linux, even if the View Component is not being reference at all.

How can I solve this? (other than opening it in Windows)

I got .NET 6 installed, and I'm testing this from a clean project created from template.

OS: Garuda Linux (arch-based)
IDE: JetBrains Rider

`Components/ProductBox.cs` contains

```
public class ProductBox : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke() => View();
}
```

`Components/ProductBox/Default.cshtml` is completely empty

Answer (score 0):

After flipping back-and-forth between the base project, a first blank project template with files copied over, and a 2nd blank project with files copied over... the View Component started to work somewhere along the lines. Got no clue where. There'sFOUND THE PROBLEM after having another problem preventing from bootingpushing the main project in Linux thoughbuild to production.

But then WebApplication1 would boot with all the same times. Started paying attention to any hidden files, likeIn Properties/launchSettingsappsettings.json. In the end; The entire application runs in WebApplication1 with all the same files, and original one still doesn't run, even after deleting obj/bin folders. Just renamed WebApplication1 to the main project name

I was facing 2 problems though. One with View Components giving a blank page, and one with failed connection.

Found the 2nd problem after having another problem pushing the build to production.

In `appsettings.json`

```json
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5003"
      }
    }
  }
```

If that configuration is present, it works in Visual Studio but fails in JetBrains Rider!

Without it; it fails to run on the server.

The solution is to move it to `appsettings.Production.json`.